# Accessing multiple data sources by name - configured in spring boot application yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource

The top-level question:  How do I use a DataSourceLookup to obtain a named DataSource that is configured in application.yml?

**Details**

I am trying to perform jdbc queries against different named datasources in a spring boot application (REST interface).

The datasource to execute against is determined at runtime based on parameters passed to the endpoint. The interactions with the datasource are all low level jdbc (no JPA or anything like that).

I want to be able to configure multiple datasources in application.yml, then obtain a DataSource object using only the name.  I don't want to explicitly configure container level jndi resources.

The connection will have high traffic, so connection pooling, etc... is a requirement (I'm assuming that Spring-Boot configures a reasonable connection pool by default).

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    source1:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url:      jdbc:mysql://dbserver.local:3306/source1
      username: myuser
      password: mypass
    source2:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      url:      jdbc:mysql://dbserver.local:3306/source2
      username: myuser
      password: mypass
```

I'm attempting to use a JndiDataSourceLookup bean (I don't think I should be using JNDI - but I can't figure out what other DataSourceLookup I should be using), as follows:

```
@RestController
public class SQLDataController {
    static final private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQLDataController.class);

    @GetMapping(value="/csv/**", produces = "text/csv")
    public void streamCsv(@RequestParam String databaseName, JndiDataSourceLookup lookup) throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = lookup.getDataSource(databaseName);
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    
}
```

When I hit this endpoint, I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:702) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:342) ~[na:na]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lambda$lookup$0(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:92) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:105) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
```

So I'm thinking I'm trying to access jndi when jndi isn't even being used (I don't really *need* JNDI, I don't think) - but I'm not sure what other DataSourceLookup I should use or how to initialize it (maybe I should be using BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup somehow?).

I'm fairly new to Spring, and all of the examples I can find assume a fixed set of datasources that are known at compile time.

---

**Update: Using BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup**

Per suggestions, I'm creating a BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup in my app configuration (with singleton scope - not sure if that important or not).

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope("singleton")
    public DataSourceLookup createDataSourceLookup() {
        return new BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup();
    }
}
```

And I'm injecting it into the controller constructor:

```
@RestController
public class SQLDataController {
    static final private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQLDataController.class);

    private final DataSourceLookup datasourceLookup;
    
    @Autowired
    public SQLDataController(ApplicationContext appContext, DataSourceLookup datasourceLookup) {
        this.datasourceLookup = datasourceLookup;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value="/csv/**", produces = "text/csv")
    public void streamCsv(@RequestParam String databaseName) throws Exception {
        DataSource dataSource = datasourceLookup.getDataSource(databaseName);
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    
}
```

When I hit the endpoint, I'm getting error that the named bean doesn't exist.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'source1' available
```

This is making me think that maybe I'm doing something wrong with the application.yml file format...  Or maybe I am misunderstanding this entirely and I have to manually enumerate the datasources and create beans for them myself?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a database lookup. Inject the `ApplicationContext` and just do `applicationContext.getBean(name, DataSource.class)`. The `BeanFactoryDataSourceLookup` would also work if you pre-configure it as a bean and inject it as a dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks.  I've updated the question with the changes I've made per your suggestion.  Now I'm getting errors that the named bean doesn't exist.  Am I doing something wrong in the application.yml file?

Comment: Well just adding that information to the yaml doesn't do anything. You will need to create beans for it, spring will not automatically create beans for you for this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for being patient with me (new to Spring .  I think this effectively means that I have to hard code a DataSource bean for every data source...